# Custom Authorization Attribute on Asp.Net Core Graphql Hot Chocolate Mutation

Tags: .net, .net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I have a mutation method. I want to call my custom authorize attribute before it.

```
[CustomAuthorize]
        public async Task<bool> ImageAdd([Service] IProductService productService, int productId, string fileName)
        {
            return await productService.AddImage(productId, fileName);
        }
```

But attribute not working. Is There any way to do this. Or can I catch this mutation in a middleware?

Comment: Do you have MutationType class which you could provide?

Comment: No I don't. I have to customize attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You can create custom attribute class by inheriting `AuthorizeAttribute` class provided by HotChocolate and overriding `TryConfigure` method. Be aware that if you don't call base method implementation you have to add authorize directive by yourself. You can see default implementation in [AuthorizeAttribute.cs file in HotChocolate GitHub repo](https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/blob/5f0e65fe0c674e40ecb64cedc0d195492cdc08ff/src/HotChocolate/AspNetCore/src/AspNetCore.Authorization/AuthorizeAttribute.cs#L23)

```cs
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public sealed class OnlyJoshAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void TryConfigure(IDescriptorContext context, IDescriptor descriptor, ICustomAttributeProvider element)
        {
            Policy = "PeopleNamedJosh";
            base.TryConfigure(context, descriptor, element);
        }
    }
    
    [OnlyJosh]
    public class JoshMutations
    {
        public string Hello() => "I'm Josh 100%!";
    }
```

Comment: thank you fo your answer Dalibor. I have solved in a different way.

Comment: Why can't I give you more than one upvote... This saved me lots of trouble.

Comment: @onur.k Hi can you tell me how you implement the custom attribute to authorize

       [HasPermission("can_read")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Job>> GetJobs(GetJobsQuery query)
        {
            return await _mediator.Send(query);
        }
 
I want this kind of thing

Answer (score -1):

You can specify Authorization in your MutationType

```
public class MutationType : ObjectType<Mutation>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Mutation> descriptor)
    {


        descriptor.Field(x => x.ImageAdd(default!, default!, default!))
            .Type<ImageTye>()
            .Name("AddImage") //Through this name you can access it in playground
            .Argument("productId", a => a.Type<LongType>())
            .Authorize(new[] { "Specific Role" });

    }
}
```

Make sure you add `.AddAuthorization()` and `.AddMutationType<MutationType>()` to services and `app.UseAuthentication();` as well.

If you choose this way you have to describe every Mutation this way, because you can only add one MutationType (use `.AddMutationType<MutationType>()` once)

Comment: flzzz thanks for your answer. But I have to customize Authorize Attribute. I have to majke many different controls

Comment: Alright. That was my solution, because i could't make the approach you are using working.